# Does there exist a non-zero signed finite borel measure which is zero on all balls?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact separable metric space. Let $\mu$ be a Borel, regular, finite, **signed** measure on $X$ such that for all $x\in X$, for all $r>0$, $\mu(B(x,r))=0$, where $B$ denotes the (either open or closed) ball w.r.t $d$.

Is $\mu$ zero?

If $\mu$ is positive one can show that $\mu=0$ using the Borel-Lebesgue theorem, but what if $\mu$ is signed?

Comment: The set of balls generates the Borel sigma-algebra, so that $\mu$ is characterized by its values on balls and must be zero (if you are more comfortable with positive measures, think about the decomposition of $\mu$ into its positive and negative part, and observe that they have the same values on all balls and thus coincide).

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Erm... How do you show that the family of zero measure sets is a $\sigma$-algebra? Usually you can do it if you start with a semi-ring using the monotone class lemma, but balls do not form one. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: The usual argument for this needs a collection which not only generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra but is also closed under finite intersections (a $\pi$-system), which the balls do not satisfy.

Comment: @fedja and NateElredge I have been naïve, thanks for the correction and sorry for my erroneous comment..

Answer (score 12):

Stealing [an answer from "user940" on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022647/equality-of-two-borel-measures), the answer is yes, such measures can exist.  In the paper

> *Davies, Roy O.*, [**Measures not approximable or not specifiable by means of balls**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300005386), Mathematika, Lond. 18, 157-160 (1971). [ZBL0229.28005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0229.28005).

the author constructs a compact metric space $X$ and two distinct Borel probability measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$ that agree on every closed ball.  (They must therefore also agree on open balls, because an open ball is a countable increasing union of closed balls.)  Taking $\mu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ provides your desired signed measure.

Comment: On the positive side, the answer to whether $\mu$ is zero is yes for Banach spaces; as proved by D. Preiss and J. Tiser, Measures in Banach spaces are determined by their values on balls. Mathematika 38, No. 2, 391-397 (1991). [Zbl 0755.28006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0755.28006)

Comment: @Dirk Werner : Preiss and Tiser claim to show this for general Banach spaces in the title and the abstract, but the Theorem itself is formulated and proved for *separable* Banach spaces only. Do you know whether the general statement holds? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't the support of a (regular finite) measure be separable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am not familiar with this result, could you please point me to a reference?

So your argument would be: Consider the support of the (regular finite) measure, which is separable. Then take the closure of its linear span, which is a (possibly smaller) separable Banach space and work therein.

Is this correct?

Comment: @iljusch: Let $E$ be the support.  [If it is not separable then it contains an uncountable set $S$ with no limit points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854087/x-d-is-separable-if-and-only-if-x-does-not-contain-an-uncountable-closed-d).  So for each $x \in S$ we can find an open ball $B(x, r_x)$ containing no other points of $S$.  Then the balls $B(x, r_x/2)$ are pairwise disjoint. But since $x$ is in the support, each of these uncountably many disjoint balls must have positive measure.  This is impossible for a finite or $\sigma$-finite measure.

Comment: Thank you, Nate!